# ¿Como comparar una cadena de texto de un fichero con una variable en C?

Tags: c

tengo problemas con un ejercicio en C. Necesito comparar una cadena de texto guardada en un fichero.

Contenido del fichero (client.txt):

```
Jose     Gomez   Santos
Maria    Sanz    Trementina
Jesus    Gomez   Soler
```

Nombre, apellido, segundo apellido

He de comparar el primer apellido de todos con uno que el usuario introduzca.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 3 //Quantitat de personas al arxiu 'clients.c'

int main() {

FILE *file;
char linea[1024];
char *persona1, *persona2, *persona3;
char *frase1;
char *frase2;
char *frase3;
char *persona;
int i;

file = fopen("clients.txt", "w+");


persona1 = "Jose \t Gomez\t Santos\n";
persona2 = "Maria \t Sanz\t Trementina\n";
persona3 = "Jesus \t Gomez\t Soler\n";

fwrite(persona1, 1, strlen(persona1), file);
fwrite(persona2, 1, strlen(persona2), file);
fwrite(persona3, 1, strlen(persona3), file);


rewind(file);

printf("Introduix el primer cognom d'una de les persones\n");
scanf("%s", persona );

printf("------------------------------\n");
printf("PERSONES EN EL FITXER\n");



for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
  fgets(linea, 1024, file);
  puts(linea);
  frase1 = strtok(linea, "\t");
  frase2 = strtok(NULL, "\t");
  frase3 = strtok(NULL, "\t");

if( strcmp(persona , frase2) == 0 )
{
printf("Aquest cognom existeix !!\n");
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", frase1, frase2, frase3);
} else {
 printf("Aquest cognom no existeix\n");
}
 printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");
}
fclose(file);
}
```

El error que presenta mi código es que no me permite comparar en el "strcmp" las variable con el apellido que inserta el usuario "persona", con el apellido de la variable "frase2" que contiene el fichero llamado "clients.txt".

El error que me da es "core generado" y no se qual es el error concreta mente.
 Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Hola @GokuGod97, por favor especifica cuál es el problema o error que presenta tu código, porque no queda claro.

Comment: Vale, ahora especifico mejor

Comment: C es "ñoño" con los strings, " Gomez" no es lo mismo que "Gomez", practicamente todos los lenguajes de programación son así.

Comment: Pero en caso de que no sea lo mismo me debería mostrar la parte del "else" conforme que ese apellido no existe vaya, según pienso yo.

Comment: El programa "crashea" cuando intento reproducir el problema, algún detalle de tu lado?

Comment: El programa "crashea" cuando intento comparar en el "strcmp" entre ambas variables (persona, frase2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cambia persona por persona[1024], porque la estas declarando como un puntero, y nunca alocas memoria (dinamico o estatica) para guardar esos datos, entonces el scanf te pisa otros datos

Comment: vale muchas gracias.